# Bit shifting a character with wrap? C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I have a binary file that will be read in as characters.  Each character was bit shifted to the left unknown number of times (assuming with wrap) by someone else.  I want to be able to read in each character and then wrap shift to the right (the number of times to shift I guess will have to be figured out manually, because I haven't figured out another way).

So, my current idea is that I read in a character, create a copy with temp and then use XOR:

```
char letter;    //will hold the read in letter
char temp;      //will hold a copy of the letter
while(file.read(&letter, sizeof(letter)) //letter now holds 00001101
{
    temp = letter;  //temp now holds 00001101
    letter >>= 1;   //shift 1 position to the right, letter now holds 00000110
    temp <<= 7;     //shift to the left by (8-1), which is 7, temp now holds 10000000
    letter ^= temp; //use XOR to get the wrap, letter now holds 10000110
    cout << letter;
}
```

That makes sense in my exhausted head, but it doesn't work... and I can't figure out why.  Size of char is 1 byte, so I figured I only have to mess around with 8 bits.

Comment: You've told us what you expect - what do you actually get?

Comment: @sftrabbit Some cryptic looking mess.

Comment: You're reading to `letter` twice per loop, discarding the first-read value

Comment: I recommend using inline assembly language because many assembly languages can shift into carry and shift carry in.  Some may also have rotate instructions.  Such a pain to code in C or C++.

Comment: @jthill Oh yeah, sorry, bad pasting on my part. :)

Comment: All works now, thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pay attention to the signess of a char. On many systems it is signed. So your `letter >>= 1` is sign filling the shift.

Rotating integers is usually done as follows

```
letter = ((unsigned char)letter >> 1) | (letter << 7);
```

As Mark points out in the comments, you can use either OR `|` or XOR `^`.

Comment: BOOM! That worked my friend!  Thank you so much.  I didn't use the edited code, but I'll try.  What I did was read in a cast of char to an unsigned char and it worked like a charm.  Thanks so much for pointing out the unsigned thing... can't believe I missed it.

Comment: If there are no overlapping bits, `or` and `xor` will produce the same results.

Comment: Your answer gave me signessitis.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `temp <<= 7` is losing the bits that you want to wrap.
 You will need to loop shifting left one bit at a time. First checking the most significant char bit and if set moving it to the right most bit before doing the shift.

Comment: temp is shifted 7 to the left because letter is shifted to the right once.  When I use XOR on both of them, it gives me that bit that got dropped on the right side (and now it's on the left side, wrapped around).

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use a larger integral type:

```
unsigned val = (unsigned)letter & 0xFF;
val |= val << 8;
```

Now you just have to shift values in `val`, without any additional code to wrap the high bits back in.